# obtain value from an anonymous object

Tags: c#, datagrid, anonymous-types

I have a list of anonymous types in a DataGrid, and I need obtain the first value (EmployeeId), that is a integer.

when I compile the application I can see the values charged in the variable(selectedEmployee).

like this:

```
selectedEmployee = 
{
    EmployeeId = 402350236,
    OperatorNum = 12,
    StateName = "Active",
    Name = "Robert",
    LastName = "Tedd Zelaya",
    Password = "abcd",
    DateBegin = {13/07/2011 0:00:00},
    DateEnd = {23/07/2011 0:00:00},
    Telephone = "8869-2108",
    Address = "Santa Barvara"
    ... 
}
```

this is my code when the user clic on the item in the grid.

```
var selectedEmployee = _employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item;
```

Also I try with this:

```
DataRowView dataRowView = _employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item as DataRowView;
            var idEmployee = 0;
            if (dataRowView != null) 
            {
                idEmployee = Convert.ToInt32(dataRowView.Row[0]);
            }
```

But the dataRowView is always Null. Not work...

how can I obtain the first value from that object?

Comment: was any of this helpful? If so, please accept a solution

Answer (score 4):

The items in your grid are not `DataRowView`'s, they are anonymous.  You'll have to use reflection or alternatively, use `dynamic`.

```
dynamic currentItem = _employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item;
int idEmployee = currentItem.EmployeeId;
```

On the other hand, it would be better if you used a strongly typed object instead.  Create the class for it or use a `Tuple` (or other).

Answer (score 0):

The `DataRowView` is null because `CurrentCell.Item` is an object with an anonymous type, not a DataRowView. The `as` operator casts the LHS to the type specified on the RHS or returns null if the item can't be cast to the RHS.

Since `CurrentCell.Item` is of an anonymous type you can't cast it to retrieve the EmployeeId. I suggest creating a class with the desired properties (call it the `Employee` class) and binding your datagrid to a collection of those Employees. Then you could say

```
var selectedEmployee = (Employee)_employeedataGrid.CurrentCell.Item;
int? selectedId = selectedEmployee == null? (int?)null : selectedEmployee.EmployeeId;
```